# wait dynamically inserted content to exist

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am doing an simple get request to get a page which has scripts that dynamically insert content.

When I try to do

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: "GET",
   success: function(data, status, xhr){
      // triggered before dynamically inserted content is added
   },
   error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(error); 
   }
});
```

The success callback function is triggered and the data returned doesn't contain the dynamically inserted content. Is it possible to wait for it to be loaded? If so, any idea how?

Comment: What does `data` contain in the success callback if not the returned content?

Comment: It contains only the content which are not dynamically inserted.

Comment: I think there is some confusion here. What are you expecting the above code to do? As you have it there, it does not insert any content anywhere. The `data` variable in the success callback will contain whatever information is returned from the server that you access at the path in your `url` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood correctly the page you are fetching via get contains js code in it that issues other ajax requests whose completion you need to wait for before doing additional stuff. In that case, the best way is to have a callback function defined in your main page which you call from the success handler of the ajax call in your internal page.

If you have control over the content of the second site, you can include in it a script from the main domain. Code in this script should be able to call your callback function without cross domain security issues.

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. Your solution might work but, they are separate sites. site1 being the page I am trying to get the content from site2.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to add your content *in* the `success` callback function:

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: "GET",
   success: function(data, status, xhr){
      // insert dynamic content HERE
   },
   error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(error); 
   }
});
```

JavaScript isn't designed to "wait" because the wait takes an indefinite amount of time and it would prevent the rest of the browser from processing. If you created an infinite loop, for example, that just sits and waits, your web browser would freeze.

**UPDATE**

Be sure you are calling your `ajax` method inside the `ready` event. This will ensure that the document is loaded first.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Your JS here
});
```

Comment: I'm not trying to change anything or add any content, would just like to get the completely loaded page.

Comment: Okay, your issue is somewhat ambiguous then. You are calling your `$.ajax` in the `$(document).ready()` event method, right?